# Inserting predefined R variable inside LaTeX code

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I was wondering whether it is possible to include `variable` in LaTeX code when compiling a PDF document in R Markdown. For example, I want to use `includegraphics` to include an image from an external PDF file.

Normally I use a code similar to:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page=66, viewport = {198 391 452 623}, clip]{book.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

I wanted to use variables `pg` for pages and `trim_areas` for viewport pt (using inline `r`):

````
```{r}
trim_areas <- c(198, 391, 452, 623)
pg <- 66
```
````

And use these variables in LaTeX code:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page=`r noquote(pg)`, viewport = {`r noquote(trim_areas)`}, clip]{book.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

But this is not working and giving me an error.

Comment: Perhaps `\Sexpr{pg}`

Comment: Thank you @IRTFM appreciate your help. I am using R Markdown instead of Sweave. But I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of indexing trim_areas four times, you can try this

````
```{r}
trim_areas <- c(198, 391, 452, 623)
pg <- 66

viewport <- knitr::combine_words(trim_areas, and = "", sep = " ")
```
````

`viewport` object looks like,

```
viewport

#> 198 391 452 623
```

Then simply use this in your latex code,

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page = `r pg`, viewport = {`r viewport`}, clip]{book.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue using following code in R Markdown:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[page = `r pg`, viewport = {`r trim_areas[1]` `r trim_areas[2]` `r trim_areas[3]` `r trim_areas[4]`}, clip]{book.pdf}
\end{figure}
```